# json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, json

What causes this error in my code?

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tour_foreign ORDER BY id desc");
        $data = array();
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            $data[] = array('guide' => $row->guide);

            echo json_decode($data); //Line 167
```

error:

```
erro: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given: Line Number: 167
```

**UPDATE:**

If I use `json_encode` instead of `json_decode`, my output is this:

```
[{"guide":["\u0633\u06cc\u062f \u0633\u0639\u06cc\u062f \u062f\u0627\u062f\u0627\u0634\u0632\u0627\u062f\u0647"]},{"guide":["\u0633\u06c‌​c\u062f \u0633\u0639\u06cc\u062f \u062f\u0627\u062f\u0627\u0634\u0632\u0627\u062f\u0647"]},{"guide":null}]
```

They are persian words.

Comment: You are passing an array where a string is expected. You are creating the array in the line before - is that necessary? Why not just use `$row->guide` directly?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think you want [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode), not [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode).

Comment: if use of `json_encode` my output is this: `[{"guide":["\u0633\u06cc\u062f \u0633\u0639\u06cc\u062f \u062f\u0627\u062f\u0627\u0634\u0632\u0627\u062f\u0647"]},{"guide":["\u0633\u06cc\u062f \u0633\u0639\u06cc\u062f \u062f\u0627\u062f\u0627\u0634\u0632\u0627\u062f\u0647"]},{"guide":null}]`, they are persian word

Comment: @Selena: The `\u0633` characters are just Unicode characters that are encoded.  The first `guide` is `سید سعید داداشزاده`.  Is that right?

Comment: @Selena: Show it where?  If you echo the string (in JavaScript) they will print correctly.  You don't need to do anything special, just echo them normally.

Comment: i not want echo they in JavaScript, What do you mean of just echo them normally!?

Comment: @Selena: What are you trying to do here?  What do you want to do with the words?

Comment: I want just echo they in the `foreach`?

Comment: @Selena If you want to each them in the `foreach` why do you have `json_encode`?  Just echo them.

Answer (score 31):

> Set decoding to *true*

Your decoding is not set to true.  If you don't have access to set the source to true. The code below will fix it for you.

```
$WorkingArray = json_decode(json_encode($data),true);
```

Answer (score 3):

json_decode() is used to decode a json string to an array/data object. json_encode() creates a json string from an array or data. You are using the wrong function my friend, try json_encode();

Answer (score 2):

- Make an object

  `$obj = json_decode(json_encode($need_to_json));`
- Show data from this $obj

  `$obj->{'needed'};`

[Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-json_decode-function/)

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution for similar problem which i was facing while extracting name from user profile facebook json object

```
$uname=json_encode($userprof);
$uname=json_decode($uname);
echo "Welcome " . $uname -> name  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was running into the same issue. What I failed to notice is that I was using **json_decode()** instead of using **json_encode()** so for those who are going to come here please make sure you are using the right function, which is ***json_encode()***

Note: Depends on what you are working on but make sure you are using the right function.