# Querying a collection with an array of mongoID

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, jenssegers-mongodb

I have the following code:

```
// company_ids is an array of mongo IDs
// company_id is an array (with only 1 element) of mongo ID
foreach($company_ids as $company_id){
    $results = Archive::where("billing.company._id", 'all', array($company_id))->get();
    ...
```

Here is the output of `Log::info(print_r($company_ids, true))`

```
[2016-10-22 02:41:27] production.INFO: Array
(
    [0] => 57515764b91a8c4d008b45d1
    [1] => 57515764b91a8c4d008b45d6
    [2] => 57515764b91a8c4d008b45db
    [3] => 57515764b91a8c4d008b45e0
    ...
)
```

How can I query the `Archive` collection directly using `company_ids` and removing the need for the `foreach` loop?

Comment: have you tried just $results = Archive::where("billing.company._id", 'all', $company_ids)->get();

Comment: Yes I tried that, but the result is empty.

Comment: try maybe  $results = Archive::where("billing.company._id", 'all', json_decode('{"$in":'+json_decode($company_ids)+'}')->get();

Comment: That doesn't work as well; phpStorm complained about the wrong concatenation operator, and the 2nd json_decode errored out expecting string, which http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436925/json-decode-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-array-given solved.

This is what I end up with: 
Archive::where("billing.company._id", 'all', json_decode('{"$in":' . json_encode($company_ids) . '}')->get());
but it still errors out "Call to a member function get() on array"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small update in **@Robbie** answer. No need to use an array of `MongoIds` simply use array of string and it will work. Am using this only with laravel-jenessengers

```
$company_ids = [
    '57515764b91a8c4d008b45d1',
    '57515764b91a8c4d008b45d6',
    '57515764b91a8c4d008b45db',
    '57515764b91a8c4d008b45e0'
]

$results = Archive::whereIn('billing.company._id', $company_ids)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [readme](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#examples) for the library:

```
$results = Archive::whereIn('billing.company._id', $company_ids)->get();
```

(I'm not clear on what array $company_ids is, but I presume it needs to be and array of MongoID: but this also depends on the underlying library you are using, [Mongo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) or [MongoDB](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php), as both are supported by the library)

```
$company_ids = [
    new mongoID('57515764b91a8c4d008b45d1'),
    new mongoID('57515764b91a8c4d008b45d6'),
    new mongoID('57515764b91a8c4d008b45db'),
    new mongoID('57515764b91a8c4d008b45e0'),
]
```

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't work, $results is empty. However a similar query that doesn't compare a subdocument will work.

Comment: Actually, just re-reading your structure, `billing.company._id` looks like it's not a MongoID but is your own personal ID? If so, just pass in the array if IDs as strings. Only use new `MongoID()` if you're looking for the MongoID (`_id`) column.